# has Http 1.0 something which I must pay attention? (php, generating requests)

Tags: php, http, request

The topic is a bit strange, let me express myself.
I used this method to generate post requests:

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm

thats ok, but after a size, I realized the datas gets changes a little, there are unwanted white spaces. Only in case of a bigger size, + a "chunked" flag appeared.
I change the Http/1.1 protocol to Http/1.0 and now the transfers look good!
But is there any backward, pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a number of important differences between http 1.0 and 1.1 of course, look at [this article](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html) for an overview.

One that I can directly spot as affecting your code is

```
    // send the request headers:
    fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
```

The Host header field doesn't exist in http 1.0, and that could affect your ability to post to servers that host multiple domains and/or subdomains via [name based virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) - the server won't know what domain you're calling.

As a general note, writing a post request this way is a nice exercise and it's always good to know what goes on under the hood, but for production purposes I'd use a full-blown, well tested mechanism like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

And for reference:

- [rfc 1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt) defines http 1.0
- [rfc 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) defines http 1.1

Comment: yea, cURL solved that. I didnt think php had a sollution for this.